# Add milliseconds delay to Array.map calls which returns Array of promises

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise, settimeout

My need is simple. I would like to delay calls to `sendEmail` by 100 milliseconds. The email service provider permits at most sending 10 emails per second.

Note, however, though `.map` is synchronous, it immediately returns a `Promise`.

I have tried `setTimeout` to no avail, such as `setTimeout(() => resolve(x), 100)` and `setTimeout(() => {return new Promise....}, 100)`.

Thoughts?

```
const promises = userEmailArray.map((userEmail) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ....
      mailer.sendEmail(userEmail);
      return resolve();
    });
  });
});
...
Promise.all(promises).then(() => resolve()).catch(error => reject(error));
```

Comment: What is your mailer? And what does it give you, to let you know when it's been sent? You want the ability to wait for it to respond to you, either via promise, or via callback.

Comment: Does this run in an express or web app? If so then multiple request may be made to the server causing your api to fail because even though you restrict requests to be no more than 10 per second your function may be called multiple times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a bunch of different ways to approach this.  I'd probably just use a recursive chained promise myself and then you can more precisely use a timer based on the finish from the previous call and you can use promises for calling it and handling propagation of errors.

I've assumed here that your `mailer.sendEmail()` follows the node.js callback calling convention so we need to "promisify" it.  If it already returns a promise, then you can use it directly instead of the `sendEmail()` function that I created.

Anyways, here are a bunch of different approaches.

**Recall Same Function After Delay (delayed recursion)**

```
// make promisified version - assumes it follows node.js async calling convention
let sendEmail = util.promisify(mailer.sendEmail);

function delay(t, data) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, data), t);
    });
}

function sendAll(array) {
    let index = 0;
    function next() {
        if (index < array.length) {
            return sendEmail(array[index++]).then(function() {
                return delay(100).then(next);
            });
        }        
    }
    return Promise.resolve().then(next);
}

// usage
sendAll(userEmailArray).then(() => {
    // all done here
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
});
```

---

**Use setInterval to Control Pace**

You could also just use a setInterval to just launch a new request every 100ms until the array was empty:

```
// promisify
let sendEmail = util.promisify(mailer.sendEmail);

function sendAll(array) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let index = 0;
        let timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (index < array.length) {
                sendEmail(array[index++]).catch(() => {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    reject();                        
                });
            } else {
                clearInterval(timer);
                resolve();
            }
        }, 100);
    })
}
```

---

**Use await to Pause Loop**

And, you could use `await` in ES6 to "pause" the loop:

```
// make promisified version - assumes it follows node.js async calling convention
let sendEmail = util.promisify(mailer.sendEmail);

function delay(t, data) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, data), t);
    });
}

// assume this is inside an async function    
for (let userEmail of userEmailArray) {
    await sendEmail(userEmail).then(delay.bind(null, 100));
}
```

---

**Use `.reduce()` with Promises to Sequence Access to Array**

If you aren't trying to accumulate an array of results, but just want to sequence, then a canonical ways to do that is using a promise chain driven by `.reduce()`:

```
// make promisified version - assumes it follows node.js async calling convention
let sendEmail = util.promisify(mailer.sendEmail);

function delay(t, data) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, data), t);
    });
}

userEmailArray.reduce(function(p, userEmail) {
    return p.then(() => {
        return sendEmail(userEmail).then(delay.bind(null, 100));
    });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(() => {
    // all done here
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
});
```

---

**Using Bluebird Features for both Concurrency Control and Delay**

The [Bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) has a couple useful features built in that help here:

```
const Promise = require('Bluebird');
// make promisified version - assumes it follows node.js async calling convention
let sendEmail = Promise.promisify(mailer.sendEmail);

Promise.map(userEmailArray, userEmail => {
    return sendEmail(userEmail).delay(100);
}, {concurrency: 1}).then(() => {
    // all done here
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
});
```

Note the use of both the `{concurrency: 1}` feature to control how many requests are in-flight at the same time and the built-in `.delay(100)` promise method.

---

**Create Sequence Helper That Can Be Used Generally**

And, it might be useful to just create a little helper function for sequencing an array with a delay between iterations:

```
function delay(t, data) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t, data);
    });
}

async function runSequence(array, delayT, fn) {
    let results = [];
    for (let item of array) {
        let data = await fn(item);
        results.push(data);
        await delay(delayT);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Then, you can just use that helper whenever you need it:

```
// make promisified version - assumes it follows node.js async calling convention
let sendEmail = util.promisify(mailer.sendEmail);

runSequence(userEmailArray, 100, sendEmail).then(() => {
    // all done here
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
});
```

Comment: @user1322092 - I added a total of 6 different ways to do this.

Comment: **Use await to Pause Loop** won't work, as the callback will return a promise for each item in the array immediately. So after 100ms all the calls will be basically made at once.

Comment: @Inkling - I don't know what you're trying to comment on.   `await` will indeed pause the `for/of` loop.  `runSquence()` will return a promise immediately, and will resolve when the entire `for` loop is done.  Yes, `fn()` will be called for each item in the array (one at a time) as that is the point of this code.  It is not true that after 100ms all the calls will be done.  Perhaps you don't understand what `await` inside a `for` loop does.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're not doing it inside a `for` loop, you're doing it inside a `.map` callback. You cannot get promises to resolve sequentially (delay or not) using `.map` with an `async` function, this is a common error.

Comment: @Inkling - Which code block are you commenting on?  If it's `Promise.map()`, that is a specific feature of the Bluebird promise library that does wait on promises returned from the `.map()` callback.  That's not `array.map()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 "Use await to Pause Loop". It contains `userEmailArray.map`.

Comment: @Inkling - Got it.  Corrected now.  Didn't know what you were looking at for awhile.

Comment: Highly useful examples, I still learn lots from them. Thank you. In your `Create Sequence Helper That Can Be Used Generally` the sequence of the parameters in the function vs. the sequence of the arguments in the function call is mixed up. `delayT, fn` should be `fn, delayT`. For people searching for a function that returns a promise and then want to request an array of URLs, here is an example. https://jsfiddle.net/maxro5n8/ @jsfriend00 if you can edit the fiddle to address the warnings on line 31 and 32, that would be ace. Bottom line, solid stuff, thx. :)

Comment: @lowtechsun - I fixed the argument order thing and fixed what was causing those two warnings in the answer.  You can apply those changes to your fiddle.

Comment: Thank you. I adjusted the code per your change. However a) now I am struggling to fetch more than 1 item from the array of URLs, kindly see https://jsfiddle.net/1t32gxp8/ if you find some time, and b) using VSCode and ESLint I do not get those warnings that are shown in JSFiddle - how could I enable those warnings in VSCode/ESLint as well? That might help me get the code right even more.

Comment: @lowtechsun - I made some more corrections.  You can see them in the answer above and here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ad2hx8L6/.  I don't know anything about VSCode.

Comment: In your jsfiddle you push to results in `fetchHTML` and `runSequence`, resulting in 1 item being pushed to results - and `await delay(delayTime);` should be `await delay(delayTime, data);`. I find that `let results..` has to be outside `fetchHTML` and not inside `runSequence`, so that `runSequence` does not re-push to the same initialised array on every call. If you keep it as you have it the array items will be undefined. I changed `.json` to `.text` so u see the sequence logging with the delay. https://jsfiddle.net/69hkron1/

Comment: @lowtechsun - If the resolved value from `delay()` is not being used, there is no need to pass the 2nd argument.  That argument is optional.

Comment: @lowtechsun - I'm sorry, but I'm not going to work on your jsFiddle any more.  There's one last update [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ad2hx8L6/).  If you have a question about your specific jsFiddle, then you can post your own question about that.  FYI, you don't need to be collecting results in `fetchHTML` as `runSequence()` is already collecting the results.

Answer (score 10):

You already have a 'queue' of sorts: a list of addresses to send to. All you really need to do now is pause before sending each one. However, you don't want to pause for the same length of time prior to each send. That'll result in a single pause of n ms, then a whole raft of messages being sent within a few ms of each other. Try running this and you'll see what I mean:

```js
const userEmailArray = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]
const promises = userEmailArray.map(userEmail =>
  new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(userEmail)
      resolve()
    }, 1000)
  )
)
Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log('done'))
```

Hopefully you saw a pause of about a second, then a bunch of messages appearing at once! Not really what we're after.

Ideally, you'd delegate this to a worker process in the background so as not to block. However, assuming you're not going to do that for now, one trick is to have each call delayed by a different amount of time. (Note that this does *not* solve the problem of multiple users trying to process large lists at once, which presumably is going to trigger the same API restrictions).

```js
const userEmailArray = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]
const promises = userEmailArray.map((userEmail, i) =>
  new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(userEmail)
      resolve()
    }, 1000 * userEmailArray.length - 1000 * i)
  )
)
Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log('done'))
```

Here, you should see each array element be processed in roughly staggered fashion. Again, this is not a scaleable solution but hopefully it demonstrates a bit about timing and promises.

Comment: Thanks, Rich, really appreciate the insights!!

Comment: YW. I can't stress enough about not doing this at scale though ;) it just might be helpful to people who are still learning about how promises work.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to just do an async iteration of the array.

```
function send(i, arr, cb) {
  if (i >= arr.length) return cb();

  mailer.sendEmail(arr[i]);
  setTimeout(send, 100, i+1, arr, cb);
}
send(0, userEmailArray, function() { console.log("all done") });
```

Comment: Thanks - but how do you incorporate promises? I need all promises to be resolved (`Promise.all`) before sending back a response (or I guess return an error if one is rejected).

Comment: @user1322092: You don't need promises for that. Have `send` receive a callback, which is invoked the`if` statement. Much shorter, simpler and clearer code this way.